# Python dictionary to CSV in required format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a python dictionary that looks like the following:

```
{
  key1: [value1, value2, value3, n],
  key2: [value1, value2, value3, n],
  key3: [value1, value2, value3, n],
  key4: [value1, value2, value3, n]
}
```

I would like to write these values to a csv file in the format where each line contains Keys as header and associated values(row by row) under that key.

Comment: Please show the CSV output you want to achieve.

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame(your_dict).to_csv('file.csv')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) can provide you with a more direct way of achieving this, but if you simply want to rely on the `csv` package from the standard library, the following naive approach should do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv


data = {
    'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n'],
    'key2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n'],
    'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n'],
    'key4': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n']
}

header = data.keys()
no_rows = len(data[list(header)[0]])

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    for row in range(no_rows):
        csvwriter.writerow([data[key][row] for key in header])
```

This results in

```
key1,key2,key3,key4
value1,value1,value1,value1
value2,value2,value2,value2
value3,value3,value3,value3
n,n,n,n
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Since this is now the accepted answer, I feel that I should add that [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) does indeed provide a more direct way of achieving this, as mentioned in other answers:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

produces the same output as above (possibly with different line terminators, depending on your system).

Comment: While it is true that Pandas offers that option, doesn't it create a copy of the data to store it as a pd.DataFrame object, therefore (at least) duplicating the memory needed? Because that might be costly in some applications where the dictionary is not just a small one.

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` provides a very straight forward solution to the problem -

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n'],
  'key2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n'],
  'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n'],
  'key4': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'n']
})
df.to_csv('/path/to/file')
```